# Why the variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

```
function foo(){
    var filename="xxx.txt";   
    var readtxt;
    var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
            getService(Ci.nsIProperties).
            get("Home", Ci.nsIFile);
    file.append(filename);
    NetUtil.asyncFetch(file, function(inputStream, status) {
        if (!components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
            // Handle error!
            console.log("file read error.."+filename);
            return;
        }
        // The file data is contained within inputStream.
        // You can read it into a string with
        readtxt = NetUtil.readInputStreamToString(inputStream, inputStream.available());
        console.log("firstly print="+readtxt);
    });
    console.log("secondly print="+readtxt);
}
```

The purpost of the code is to read from a file and then print it.
In the above code, I define a `var readtxt`. Then in line `console.log("firstly print="+readtxt);`, `readtxt` is successfully printed. However, in line `console.log("secondly print="+readtxt);` it says `secondly print=undefined`. I don't know why.

Comment: A little tip: using proper indentation always helps when sorting out scope issues.

Comment: Does the second print appear in the console *before* the first print?

Comment: `NetUtil.asyncFetch` - the **async** is the important part here ...

Comment: second print appears after first print

Comment: Second print cannot be guranteed to happen before the `firstly print`. Its an async function which means that it works like `setTimeout(function() { readtxt = 'hi' }, 5000)` except that `5000` in this example doesnt apply to your case, it does it as fast as it can but this is usually longer than it takes to get to the next line.